# Live Wallpaper Preview Thumbnail Size

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

What's the width and height of the live wallpaper preview thumbnail in pixels? It's definitely larger than 72x72, that I know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

150 x 150 at 72dpi produces a very crisp preview image (on the DroidX anyway).

Comment: what you meant by at 72dpi ??

Answer (score 2):

I did a test by taking a screenshot of the wallpaper list in the emulator. It shows the medium DPI thumb version and had exactly 75x75 pixels. Since 75x2=150 you could saved yourself some pixels ;)